# Defining a new minipage environment with xparse - Error: emergency stop

Tags: captions, environments, minipage, xparse

I would like to have an easier time writing figures, tables, lisitngs et cetera, while at the same time ensuring that any captions stay on the same page as the respective document elements. I tried the following with xparse:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{minitopcapt}{O{\textwidth}mm}{
  \minipage{#1}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=#2}
    \captionof{#2}{#3}
    \begin{#2}
}{
    \end{#2}
  \endminipage
}

\begin{document}

% This should produce a minipage-enclosed lstlisting environment
% with a caption on top of it.
\begin{minitopcapt}{lstlisting}{A caption here}

  Text

  Some more text

\end{minitopcapt}

\end{document}
```

With this I get two errors:

```latex
Emergency stop.
<*> /path/to/main/document
```

and

```latex
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!SyncTeX written on main.synctex.gz.
```

The second one is not very informative but the first one might be. I just don't know how to interpret it. How might I get the result I want, which is a listing inside a minipage with a caption on top?

Comment: you can not define new verbatim like environments like this - they don't find the end. Looks in the documentation of listings, there is described how you can define a new one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would this work with non-verbatim environments?

Comment: try it out, e.g. with center.